# How do I add opacity to CSS sidebar (not all the elements)?

Tags: css, opacity

I have this site and I'm trying to add opacity to the sidebar, but only the white part and leve the other elements with a 100 percent opacity.

http://eparquitectos.mx/

here is my CSS

I tried adding

opacity:0.4; in .sidebar but everything received the same opacity, including text and logo.

```
SIDEBAR
*************************************************************************/
.sidebar {
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
padding:50px 0 0 0;
width:220px;
height:100%;
left:50px;
top:0;
}

.sidebar.sidebar_absolute{
left:0;
position: absolute;
}

.sidebar.sidebar_absolute .inner_sidebar{
padding-bottom:67px;
}

.inner_sidebar{
width:220px;
float: left;
}

.fullwidth .sidebar{
display:none;
}

.border-transparent{
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.border-transparent-right{
left:auto;
right:0;
}

div .border-transparent-top{
height:1px;
width:100%;
}


#top .logo, .logo a{
display:block;
position:relative;
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
float:left;
text-align: center;
}

#top .logo a, #top .logo a:hover{
top:0;
left:0;
outline:none;
border: none;
}

#top .logo img{
border:none;
margin:0 auto;
max-width: 180px;
}

#top .bg-logo, #top .bg-logo a{
text-indent: -9999px;
height:85px;
width:180px;
}


/*menu*/

.main_menu, #top .main_menu .menu{
line-height:30px;
z-index:300;
clear:both;
width:100%;
position: relative;
}

.main_menu div{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index:300;
}

.main_menu .menu, .main_menu .menu ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
position:relative;
line-height:50px; 
z-index:5;
}

#top .main_menu .menu a{
display:block;
line-height:18px;
outline:medium none;
padding:9px 0;
text-decoration:none;
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
width:100%;
z-index:5;
}

.main_menu .menu li a strong {
display:block;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:normal;
cursor: pointer;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main_menu .menu li a span {
display:block;
font-size:11px;
line-height:14px;
color:#999;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Child elements inherit a parents opacity. You are better off creating semi-transparent .png and using that as a background for the the sidebar.

Comment: background-image:url('http://eparquitectos.mx/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/fondo.png');  in .sidebar

Comment: Yes. Whatever div you wish to have the semi-transparency, set it's background image in css to a semi-transparent 1x1 pixel .png.

Comment: I'm trying to add something like this in sidebar.php   echo "<div class='inner_sidebar' style="background-image: url(fondo.png);">";

Comment: Remember that background image value is quoted: url('fondo.png');

Answer (score 0):

Look up the rgba() property. It allows you to specify a color for like backgrounds with transparency.

Opacity affects the entire elements including the children. I believe what you are looking for is rgba()

Here is a snippet explination from a book I have

> The Alpha channel (Alpha for short) is the measure of the transparency of a color—as opposed to the opacity property, which is the measure of the trans- parency of an element. So although color values using Alpha can be inher- ited by child elements like any other color value, the overall opacity of the element is not affected.
>   CSS3 introduces Alpha as a value in the RGBA color model. RGBA stands for Red, Green, Blue, Alpha, and the syntax is the same as for the RGB value used in CSS2 but with the Alpha value specified by an extra comma-separated argument at the end: i.e. `{ color: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha); }`

Comment: thanks I solved it with echo "<div class='box'style='background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);'>";

Comment: It won't work in IE versions earlier than IE 9. See:
http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: There are polyfills and "hacks" to make this work on IE. He asked a question and I provided him an answer on how to do this with a property that was made for his exact scenario. IE messes everything up I am not living for IE. There are polyphills and "hacks" to fix the terrible browser known as IE as I mentioned earlier